# How to config pip index-url in Kolla-Ansible?

Tags: docker, ansible, openstack

I have some private packages deployed in internal server, I want to config pip in Kolla-Ansible's images. Is there any config options I can modify to achieve this? Is the pip config same with the virtural environment which I installed Kolla-Ansible?

Answer (score 1):

> Is the pip config same with the virtural environment which I installed Kolla-Ansible?

IIUC, no. In my experiment, the host's `pip config` is different with the virtual environment. Like this:

```
root@l-pc:~# pip -V
pip 20.2 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)

root@l-pc:~# pip config list
global.index-url='http://my.host.com/pypi/simple'
install.trusted-host='my.host.com'


root@l-pc:~# docker exec -it -u 0 nova_compute /bin/bash

(nova-compute)[root@l-pc /]# pip -V
pip 20.3.1 from /var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)

(nova-compute)[root@l-pc /]# pip config list
:env:.extra-index-url='https://mirror.iad.rax.opendev.org/wheel/ubuntu-18.04-x86_64'
:env:.index-url='http://mirror.iad.rax.opendev.org:8080/pypi/simple'
:env:.trusted-host='mirror.iad.rax.opendev.org'
```

> config pip in Kolla-Ansible's images. Is there any config options I can modify to achieve this?

In my view, it could be yes. All according to the docker container's virtual environment files(**/etc/resolv.conf, /etc/hosts**) will update consist with the host's while it start.

So you could achieve that by update files before deploy the docker image or restart the running docker container.

- add the `1.1.1.1 mirror.iad.rax.opendev.org` resolve in **/etc/hosts**, which `1.1.1.1` is your internal server and `mirror.iad.rax.opendev.org` is the default index-url in image.

or

- insert `nameserver 1.1.1.2` in **/etc/resolv.conf** if you have your `DNS server: 1.1.1.2` which would resolve the image default `index-url: mirror.iad.rax.opendev.org` domain name.

> config pip in Kolla-Ansible's images

- update the image's `.pip/pip.conf` with `extra-index-url public.pip.server.com` after `index-url your.internal.server.com`，it will looks for `extra-index-url` while it can not found in `index-url`. But in this way, you could exec `docker commit` to create your new image.

Comment: I only host my packages on the internal pypi server, if resolve `mirror.iad.rax.opendev.org` to the internal server then I could not download public packages.(It's my guess, I haven't try it)

Comment: Whether your private packages in internal server have the same name with the public packages or not? If no, maybe you need to update the image's `pip config` with `--extra-index-url public.pip.server.com` after `index-url your.internal.server.com`.  If yes, I suggest that you should maintain the all packages which you need, some produce by yourself as other download from public server. One more thing, does your internal pypi server could access public network? If yes, maybe you could configure proxy some public packages in internal server.

Comment: my private packages in internal server have the same name with the public packages, so I want to make internal pypi server as `index-url`, public server as `extra-index-url`. I have created base ubuntu image with a pip.conf file but get no luck. Then I tried to change kolla/docker/openstack-base/Dockerfile.j2 (jinja2 template), add `http://1.1.1.1/packages/mypackage-0.0.1.tar.gz` into `set openstack_base_pip_packages`, it worked. I haven't figure out why pip.conf  does not change the setting, the solution is just not good and temporary.

Comment: Have you check `index-url` and `extra-index-url` setting could work by manual?

Comment: I forgot  if I ever tested this, I think it will work fine. But I remember that add private packages into `requirements.txt` in the openstack service source code did not trigger download, so the question is how can I make kolla-ansible download my private packages. The solution I found is to change template file. Anyway, thanks for your answer!

Comment: Oh, I know, thanks for share your effort. Maybe my answer is reply to: how configure pip index-url in kolla-ansible's docker image. And you could answer your question by your suitable solution and accept it. Check from "https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer". Cheer.